# How can I write VBA to compare every cell on one sheet to every shell on another sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare each cell on one sheet to each cell on another sheet and then highlight the differences. For example, I want to see if cell a2 on one sheet is the same as cell a2 on another sheet. At one point, I was able to run a comparison, but it was just looking for a match within the whole sheet, not just specific cells, so I was getting false positives. I am obviously missing the piece that makes the cell to cell comparison. New to VBA so here is what I have cobbled together so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim cell As Variant

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:Z5000"

    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = Worksheets("RoboReader").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Uploader").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                ' Cells are identical.
                ' Do nothing.
            Else

                Cells.Font.Bold = True
                Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 2
                Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid


            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

End Sub
```

Comment: From what I'm reading the logic looks good, can you add some screenshots of example data including some false positives? Also might be worth setting up a small example range and replicate a false positive, then step through your loops to see why it's not comparing right.

Answer (score 1):

### Cell by Cell Comparison

- When using Cells without a qualifier, it means `all` (1048576*16384)
  cells on the `Activesheet`.
- When you use the equal sign (`=`) in an `If` statement, the opposite
  is (`<>`). You can eliminate the equal part since nothing will be
  happening then.

**A Quick Fix**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim varSheetA As Variant
    Dim varSheetB As Variant
    Dim strRangeToCheck As String
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim cell As Variant

    'Worksheets("Uploader").Cells.ClearFormats

    strRangeToCheck = "A1:Z5000"
    Debug.Print Now
    varSheetA = Worksheets("RoboReader").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    varSheetB = Worksheets("Uploader").Range(strRangeToCheck)
    Debug.Print Now

    For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
        For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
            If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) <> varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
                With Worksheets("Uploader").Cells(iRow, iCol)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 8
                    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
                End With
            End If
        Next iCol
    Next iRow

End Sub
```